# Loading json fails from url, works from file

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code snippet:

```
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/images",
  function(data) {

    var items = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, val){
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
    });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');

  });
```

The url returns json that looks like `{"count" : 0}`. When I try to load the page in my browser the .getJSON call fails. However when I save the result from "http://localhost:8080/images" to a file and try to load it with the same Javascript (url replaced by file name) everything works as expected and I get a list.

Any pointers?

Comment: Do the port and host of where you are running the script from match those of `http://localhost:8080/images`?

Comment: what does webkit/firebug tell you is coming back from the server?  is the url to the json violating the same origin policy?

Comment: Yep, both browser and service (on 8080) are running on localhost. I can see the request coming in and the service answers with {"count" : 0}. Also visible when I enter the url directly in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In the normal course of things, you can only use "ajax" (that is, a genuine `XMLHttpRequest` call) to retrieve resources from the same *origin* as the document your script is running in. Origin includes domain, port, and protocol. Your loading it from the local file should only work if the document itself is loading from a local file (not an `http` URL). See the link for details.

Comment: I think I understand. This means that if I let Apache provide this same page (instead of loading it directly from file) it will work, right?

Comment: As long as the page on which the code is running is on served from a URL starting with `http://localhost:8080`, you'll be able to load `http://localhost:8080/images` on it. But if the page the code is running on were from `http://localhost` (e.g., port 80, not 8080), or if it were from `http://somewhere.else.com:8080` (different domain), you'd hit the SOP. (You also hit it if you mix `http` and `https`.)